# How can I delete all tensors from GPU with torch

Tags: python, gpu, tensor, torch

I want to delete all tensors from my GPU to free memory. How can I do it without referring to each particular tensor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to free up all memory pytorch is taken from gpu memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205412/how-to-free-up-all-memory-pytorch-is-taken-from-gpu-memory)